# aws ec2, update ubuntu with dependencies

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

In status quo, I have running `aws ec2`with `ubuntu` version `14.04`

I'm going to update version to `16.04` and I recognize that `sudo do-release-upgrade` will help me to do that.

The reason for the `ubuntu` update, is to upgrade `php5` to `php7` and to lessen deprecated `gems`

However, my worries are that, `14.04` to `16.04` brings some significant changes, for example `upstart` to `systemd`, and since I have set many configurations related to `nginx` I want to know some possible changes, or failures following such update.

Also I want to know whether `php7.0` perfectly substitute `php5` legacies.
Currently `php` is only used for wrapping `c` coded 3rd parties, and using limitedly with `php5-cli`, `php5-mcrypt`. Are these replacable by version 7?

Please share some experiences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot give you any specifics, but would recommend to use the beauty of the cloud: create an AMI snapshot of your instance and start in beside your original. Update ubuntu on the copy and see what you get.